# increment an private instance variable in object oriented program

Tags: java

table class

```
public Table() {
    height = 0.0;
    weight = 0.0;
    color = "unknown";
    numberOfLegs = 4;
    inventoryNumber = 1;
    numberOfTables++;
}// no args contructor

public Table(double h, double w, String c, int n) {
    height = h;
    weight = w;
    color = c;
    numberOfLegs = n;
    inventoryNumber = 2;
    numberOfTables++;
}// constructor
```

Runner class

```
Table kitchenTable = new Table();
Table diningTable = new Table(5.5, 9.9, "brown", 8);
Table picnicTable = new Table(3.3, 4.4, "red", 6);
Table babyTable = new Table();
```

how do I increment inventory number without making it a static varible
for example My runner class with have 2 no args constructor and System out println both but both of them has 1. while i want the first one print 1 and second one print 2

Comment: Why not make a method to increment it

Comment: Hello. You don't want to use static variable but your explanation clearly describe a static variable. You should provide a more precise explanation. Also, why you don't want to use static variable ?

Comment: I suggest to create static variable in class table called lastInventoryNumber which you will assign to inventoryNumber in both constructors and after that increment it. Then you don't have to increment this value after each creation of Table

Answer (score 0):

you have two options

**mutable**

add this method in your `Table` class

```
public void incrementInventory() {
     this.inventoryNumber++;
}
```

usage

```
Table mutableTable = new Table();
mutableTable.incrementInventory();
```

**inmutable** (recommended)

add this to your `Table` class

```
// new constructor
public Table(double h, double w, String c, int n, int inventory, int tables) {
    height = h;
    weight = w;
    color = c;
    numberOfLegs = n;
    inventoryNumber = inventory;
    numberOfTables = tables;
}

public Table incrementInventory() {
     // new Table with the same all variables and inventory + 1
     return new Table(
         this.height, this.weight , this.color , this.numberOfLegs ,
         this.inventoryNumber + 1, this.numberOfTables 
     );
}
```

usage

```
Table inmutableStateOne = new Table();
Table inventoryPlusOne = inmutableStateOne.incrementInventory();
```

then `inmutableStateOne` will keep your initial state and `inventoryPlusOne` is the same but with `inventory + 1`